# Elastic search error - was expecting double-quote to start field name

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to create a mapping for my new index named as `region`. Please find my below mapping file.

```
PUT region
 {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "catalog_product_id": {
            "type": "long",
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "region_id":{
          "type": "text"
          },
          "region_type":{
          "type" : "text"
          }
         }

        }
       }
      }
 }
```

While am trying to execute this mapping script am getting the below error

```
was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Comment: try to check your json for validity of any online service and you will find an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have double checked your mapping with my Kibana, and it seems that there is a parsing error on the JSON format. Remove `,` after `"type": "long",` and remove one of `}` from the end, as follows:

```
PUT region
 {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "catalog_product_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "region_id":{
            "type": "text"
          },
          "region_type":{
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Removing the ',' helped me.. thanks